# Splitting Storyboard at UITabBar level

Tags: ios, storyboard, split

I'm searching for a solution to split Storyboard at UITabBar level.
I have an app with 5 tab and i want to manage every single tab with a different storyboard.
The structure would be a simple minimal storyboard with the tab bar controller and 5 bigger storyboards with every tab viewcontrollers (and segues) which must inherit the tab bar.
Does everyone ever splitted the storyboard like this ? Any clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think it could be possible, this should go in "viewDidLoad" of your custom `UITabBarController`...

```
NSMutableArray *controllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Load the initial UIViewController from every Storyboard
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard1" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *first = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstViewController"];
[controllersArray addObject:first];

// Repeat the process with the rest
...

// Set your controllers
self.viewControllers = [controllersArray copy];
```

Remember to set an Storyboard ID for every main `UIViewController`, in the example is 'firstViewController'.

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer. The one improvement I'd make is that you don't necessarily need to give the storyboard view controllers identifiers. You can just use

    UIViewController *first = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];

Answer (score 1):

we used RBStoryboardLink  from: http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.co.il/search/label/UIStoryboard
to solve this issue